# Isolation of variables in a symbolic expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have a function that transforms symbolic Lagrange equations to Hamiltonian equations. One aspect that I have trouble with is replacing the mass*velocity term with a momentum term.

I have a line of code that returns all the momentum terms:

```
momentum = lagrangian.jacobian(velocity)
```

Which returns a symbolic matrix with cells of mass*velocity
example:

```
>>> momentum
Matrix([[0, 0, 1.0*m_1*xd2, 1.0*m_1*yd2, 1.0*m_2*td1, 1.0*m_2*td2]])
```

When I try to substitute a momentum symbolic "p" for each term, the sympy.subs function does not identify any of the mass*velocity terms. I believe this is because of the constant 1.0 in the expression. I was curious if there is a way to isolate the symbolic terms or remove the constant in front of the symbolic terms.

Comment: Exactly what `subs` command are you using.   `Matrix([[1.0*x*y]]).subs(x*y, z)` works for me.

Comment: I am trying to do Matrix([[0.5 * m * v **2]]).subs(m * v, p), but the momentum that I am trying to replace it with is "1.0 * m * v" instead of "m * v".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "remove the constant" I assume you mean that you want to make the `1.0` go away. One way to do that is to use `nsimplify` on the Matrix:

```
>>> m
Matrix([[1.0*m*v**2]])
>>> nsimplify(m, rational=True)
Matrix([[m*v**2]])
```